# How to rewrite and redirect this url?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite this url:

http://www.mydomain.com/myoldpage.php?proc=my query string (whitespace in mid)

To

http://www.mydomain.com/mynewpage.php

If a user opens old url it should redirect to new one and show content of older one.

Thanks!

Comment: Please state language and if this is a parmanent move?

Comment: I want to do it with Apache .htaccess. I'm using php

Answer (score 0):

add the php code at the top of the myoldpage.php:

```
<?php header("Location: http://www.mydomain.com/mynewpage.php"); ?>

or if you are going off a certain variable

<?php

if ($_GET['proc'] == "my"){
 header("Location: http://www.mydomain.com/mynewpage.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Chad, but I need .htaccess mod_rewrite based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply put this in you .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^myoldpage.php?proc=my+query+string$ mynewpage.php [PT]
```

Please tell me if it does not work and I will try to help you :)

Comment: What is your excakt url? You dont have to show your ip nor domain.

Comment: Yes! all three files .htaccess,old,new are in root of web directory you can see it here: http://digichroma.com/myoldpage.php?proc=my query string

Comment: Does it work if you remove ?proc=my+query+string and try to access myoldpage.php ?

Comment: I also found this to make a correct 301 redirect: RewriteRule ^myoldpage.php?proc=my+query+string$ http://digichroma.com/mynewpage.php [R=301,L]

Comment: I checked your site and for a second it worked, but didn't change the url, just the content.

Comment: I was making some changes. Actually I can achieve content on new url without query string, but if I put redirection it throws infinite redirection loop error.